# How to solve a series in which part of the term is in AP and other part is in GP?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

$k + (k-1)/2 + (k-2)/4 + ....$ so on.

What is the method to solve this series?
Since, it seems to have both AP and GP, I'm unsure how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series rewrites as $$\frac{k}{1} + \frac{k}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{4}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{8}-\frac{1}{2}+\cdots$$
However the odd-indexed terms are $$\frac{k}{1}+\frac{k}{2}+\frac{k}{4}+\cdots = 2k$$
Since those [converge absolutely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence), the convergence of the original series depends on the convergence of the even-indexed terms, namely $$-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\cdots$$
which diverge.